# Packages with user-facing generators / generator logic?

Tags: libraries

Are there any popular Emacs packages that incorporate [generators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Generators.html) in any of their user-facing functions / API?  I'm thinking of the core Emacs lisp implementation (`iter-defun`, `iter-yield`, etc.), but package use of alternatives would be fair too.

Since generators are quite new to Emacs (only introduced in v25.1?) I'm curious about what patterns/practices have been followed in applying them on a package's surface.

Using [elisp-refs](https://github.com/Wilfred/elisp-refs) I found that none of my installed packages use any Emacs core generators yet and a relatively thorough search on GitHub failed to find published package usages.

Comment: I guess they haven't been used much until now, since there are a couple of basic bugs that were only uncovered recently: [#26073](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26073) [#25965](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25965). Also [a thread about how it produces large and slow code](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2017-03/msg00264.html).

Comment: And [#26068](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26068).

Comment: @npostavs Yikes

Comment: Apparently they still haven't been used much, since there's an idea going around now that they were only introduced in Emacs 26.1. https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/05/31/ https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-06/msg00017.html, at least those old bugs have been fixed...